# Alternatives to list indicators in Android API Level 10 and below

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am in the process of making my application compatible with the earlier versions of android using the Android Compatibility library. One of the integral parts of my application is to be able to highlight the user's selection permanently in a list fragment. I was able to do this conveniently using a selector drawable in API level 11 and above using the **`android:state_activated`** property. But as it turns out this property was introduced only in API level 11.

Now I plan to achieve the same in earlier API levels, but am out of ideas. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I believe I'll need to create a separate layout for older API versions - res/layout-v10/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found an excellent solution here: http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/selectablelistview-make-selection-work/

Answer (score 0):

`View.setSelected(boolean)` (since api level 1) made the trick for me